# Execute a command as another user and get the PID for that process

Tags: linux, bash, init, pid

I'm trying to capture the PID of a program that I am running for my init script so I can come back and kill it later. When I run the script without being a different user, the command works just fine, and I get the PID in a variable. I can execute the same command as a different user, however, I cannot get the PID for that command to store in a variable. This is what I get.

```
[root@fenix-centos ~]# PID=`su - $USER -c "$DAEMONPATH $DAEMONPATHARGS $DAEMON $DAEMONARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$! "`
[root@fenix-centos ~]# echo $PID
```

...and nothing. Is there some weird thing that would prevent me from getting the PID of a process being started by a different user and storing that PID in a variable? The process still starts, but I'm not getting the PID.

Comment: cant you get it later if you know the command/program name you started and user name using pgrep,ps?

Comment: I haven't really checked, but see if changing `echo \$!` to `echo \\\$!` helps... I usually prefer putting such texts (excluding the variable expansion parts) as `'string literals'`, so that this escape, escape-escape, escape-escape-escape-escape is less confusing.

Comment: @Nachiket Its a java process, so If I were to do that, I'd end up with 10 other PIDs as well. I guess I should've said that in there as well. I'll try the escaping of the escape characters escaping other escaped characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going though the link to your script, i suggest this approach:

Perform variable (that you're passing as argument to your command su) assignment in a file:

```
[tom@jenkins ]# cat source_file
DAEMONPATH=/usr/bin/java
DAEMONPATHARGS='-jar -Xmx768'
DAEMON=/opt/megamek-0.38.0/MegaMek.jar
DAEMONARGS='-dedicated -port 2346'
```

Source the above file in your command:

```
PID=`su - $USER -c '. source_file; $DAEMONPATH $DAEMONPATHARGS $DAEMON $DAEMONARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! '`
```

It seems your syntax is not working because the `$!` must be getting evaluated by the original shell which is running `su` and not the *shell that `su` runs*.

Comment: I think the big difference is you're using single quotes, and I'm using doubles. Not sure why I didn't think of that before. When I get home to test this out, I'll let you know what my result was.

Comment: Single-quotes will pass all parameters literally to make sure that they get evaluated only by the shell in which the command will finally be running and not by its parent shell.

Comment: @Pred: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The single quotes don't allow for string substitution like double quotes do. I've also noticed that when I escape out everything, like the dollar sign, and the exclamation point, it'll just print the exclamation point. So, I guess I'm still looking.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for you. At least it worked for me. Which shell are you using? I tested on bash. Can you try putting \ before $ in the expression `$!` in the above command that i suggested?

Comment: I'll try that, but what I think is happening, is that the $DAEMON arguments are not being substituted with single quotes.

Comment: You're right about the variable substitution not happening. I didn't use variable while testing. Hmmm...i'll check and see if i get something.

Comment: It will work if you define the variables inside the command. In your case, it will be a long command line though. For ex., PID=\`su - user -c 'cmd=sleep; $cmd 60 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! '\`

Comment: That works! Now I just need to adjust my cookbook so that it automatically starts up the service. Awesome. Accepting this as my answer. I'm also wondering if you can export the variables, and my secondary user can then use it like that as well.

Comment: Well, exporting the variables was what i tried _before_ suggesting sourcing of the file. Export didn't work. :( If i find something, i'll let you know. Even i am curious to know why _export_ doesn't work.